# Change Header/Footer on all html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website and I have the header and the footer which I would change constantly. I have about 69 html pages and they are written in HTML 4.01. How can I make it so I have to change the code in, let's say the index page, and it will change for all the other pages?

I tried using Javascript which is very tedious and does not produce the same result.

[Example of a site](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/CheckSite/index.html)

Comment: Depends. What server are you using on the backend? Can you use server-side includes? Or you could load the header and footer using JavaScript (a single script that is loading into every page, so it should be a lot of work), but that won't work if the user has JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Do you know any dynamic language? E.g. PHP or even Classic ASP?

Comment: maybe a editor that can do an excellent job in find&replace? (Sublime text 2)

Comment: Tried the Javascript method, the only issue was loading the script before or after Jquery, because the site relies on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write php code wich will render content from two php files (as sample top.php and bottom.php) in all of your pages. and you can change content of this files. It looks like a widget i think).

look this simple sample:

top.php:

```
<?php
echo "top content<br>";
```

bottom.php:

```
<?php
echo "<br>bottom content";
```

index.php:

```
<?php require_once("top.php"); ?>
content
<?php require_once("bottom.php"); ?>
```

Result html is:

```
    top content
<br>
    content 
<br>
    bottom content
```

You can change top.php and bottom.php ant it will change content in index.php. If you use php server script language ;)

Comment: I guess this would be the easy way as I would just have to change them all to .PHP file and then use the include statement. Let me give this a shot. Thanks.
Question is, if the top header uses Jquery, would it still work?

Comment: You can add any content with php. You can build logic of your app as you want)

Comment: this worked out PERFECT! Thank you... the simple things we never think of!!! you will save me ALOT of times in the future. Thanks again